# height auto css issue

Tags: height, css

I tried to set the height of my [webpage](http://b2b.tangent-design.com/blog/posts/2012/march/15/b2b-new-website/#!/comments/awais/) to auto with no success. When the text grows, it overlaps the footer. Any ideas where I am getting it wrong? I want to extend the `.main` class when the text grows.

```
.main {    
    background-position: right bottom;
    min-height: 1200px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('../images/side-shape.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:auto !Important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove  this line from your footer class

margin-top: -175px;

Comment: yeh but i need to set that above the image

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to clear the float you have in your left column. Put `clear: both;` in your `footer_wrapper` and that should fix this.